# How to read nested json in flutter localization?

Tags: json, flutter, localization

I am new to flutter.

I apply localization in my flutter project and everything work fine until I edit my json language file to have nested object.

How to call the nested json object correctly?

I try call it by using dot, but it throwing error 'A non-null String must be provided...'

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Intro.Header')
```

Here is my json

```
{
  "Intro": {
    "Header": "Introduction",
    "Content": "This is...."
  },
  "Test": "This is test",
}
```

I have no issue if I call "Test" directly.

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('Test')
```

How to read Header and Content?

Comment: Try this: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate["Intro"]["Header"]

Comment: It is not working. Error state 'the operator '[]' isn't defined for the class....'. It pointing the error to "Intro"

Comment: I want to know how to do this. Any solution?

Comment: @Ooto you can have a look to my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is pretty old, but I found it as I had the same problem and was searching for a solution. I was not able to find one on the Internet so I was trying to solve it by myself and as I made it, I want to present here my solution. This solution might not be the most nice one as I am pretty new to Dart/Flutter but at least it works.

As the Owner of the question did not provide his setup I will take the state of this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lDfbbTvq4qM&t=61s) as given.

```
[...] 
Map<String, String> _localizeStrings;
[...]
_localizeStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
  return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
});
[...]
String translate(String key) {
  return _localizeStrings[key];
}
[...]
```

That is the given state, which is totally setup for a flat json structure. To be able to work with a nested structure our Map `_localizeStrings` should be of type `Map<String, dynamic>` as the key will always be a String but the value could either be a String or another map. As a next step we need to remove the `.toString()` from `value`. As a last step we will implement a function which is splitting the given key by '.' and will climb down the map key by key. The last value it gets we will return with `.toString()` as this should be the string we want to have.

So here is my solution:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _localizeStrings;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizeStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value);
    });

    return true;
  }

  String translate(String key) {
    var nestedMap = _getNestedValue(key);    
    return nestedMap.toString();
  }

  dynamic _getNestedValue(String keyPath) {
    Map keyMap = keyPath.split('.').asMap();
    var nestedMap;
    keyMap.forEach((index, key) {
      if (index == 0) {
        nestedMap = _localizeStrings[key];
      } else
        nestedMap = nestedMap[key];
    });
    return nestedMap;
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'de'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> old) => false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been struggling to solve similar problem for the past hour.